# How to proxy domain to another domain with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I tried to deploy laravel with nginx, so I wrote the ngix.conf like following and it works fine for me.

```
server {
        listen 8000 default_server;
        listen [::]:8000 default_server;

        root /home/back-stage/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                #fixes timeouts
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                include fastcgi_params;
         }
}
```

But what if I want to proxy 127.0.1:3000 to 127.0.1:8000 ?

I simply rewrote the nginx.conf like following, but it failed. How to fix it?

```
server {
        listen 3000 default_server;
        listen [::]:3000 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}

server {
        listen 8000 default_server;
        listen [::]:8000 default_server;

        root /home/back-stage/public;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9999;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                #fixes timeouts
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                include fastcgi_params;
         }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing in the first place? Also, you cannot have two `default_server` statements. Post the error messages shown when running `nginx -t`.

Comment: @herrbischoff I doing this because I want to set front and back stage on the same port. Something like 127.0.0.1:3000/front-stage/, 127.0.0.1:3000/back-stage/

Comment: @herrbischoff There was noting inside nginx error log but the browser's console got a error meesage "GET http://localhost/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
The localhost seems didn't match the 3000 port, why is that?

Comment: @herrbischoff actually you can if they are on different ports.